# Video Playing in Video Track 2 in VLC Media Player - Set Video Track

Tags: vlc, vlc.dotnet

I am currently using VlcControl ( Vlc.DotNet.Forms ) to play the video in latest VLC Media player using rtsp url in 
c# code  `_videoControl.Play(new Uri(networkUrl), options);`

*The issue here is ,the video is not playing in default Video Track 1 but it is playing in Video Track 2.*

Is there any way to set the Video Track to 1?

Kindly let me know if any options available to set the video track and play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to select the track you want to play :
(disclaimer : I'm on my phone and I didn't test the code)

```cs
mediaPlayer.SetMedia(...);
mediaPlayer.Parse();
var videoTracks = mediaPlayer.Video.Tracks.All.ToArray();
mediaPlayer.Video.Tracks.Current = videoTracks[0];

mediaPlayer.Play();
```

The same can be achieved with `Audio` for audio tracks

Comment: Thank you so much I was able to set the current track .                                                  
 Is there a way to find out in which default video track (1,2,3,4,5) the video plays?               Thanks in advance .

Comment: `mediaPlayer.Video.Tracks.CurrentTrack` also has a getter, so you can inspect that and compare to tracks from `.All`

Comment: Sorry i missed your reply. My question was wrongly framed, what i meant is the video is playing defaultly in Video Track 2 but the mediaPlayer.Video.Tracks.CurrentTrack is Video Track 1.                                 Is there a flag or method to know in which Video Track the stream is loaded?            Thanks in Advance

Comment: If `Tracks.Current` is giving you another result than the one you're expecting, either your expectations are wrong or there is a bug in libvlc. Can you try with VLC and see if you can select the track correctly? if not, you should file a bug to VLC directly and attach the video file you're trying to play

Comment: Thank you for the help. I want to do the same functionality as above but using the old version of VLC player (2014.4.18.0).

using Vlc.DotNet.Core;
using Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.Signatures.LibVlc.Media;
using Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.Signatures.LibVlc.MediaListPlayer;
using Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias;

 VlcControl _videoControl;
 String rtspUrl = networkUrl;
 var media = new LocationMedia(rtspUrl);
 media.AddOption("rtsp-tcp");
 _videoControl.Play(media);
 
 Kindly can you give more info regarding setting the video Track to 2 in old vlc
 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is unreadable and out of scope of the question. I don't know what this version is, but chances are that you will not be able to get good support for 5-year-old versions...

Comment: Hi ,I have just formatted the above comment and resubmitted question under answer section below.